# VPN connection to win2012, server gets 2nd (wrong?) IP

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2012, ip-address

I have a number of windows 2012 servers in our office network.
The servers and their local IPs:

- S01 - 192.168.16.2
- M01 - 192.168.16.3
- S02 - 192.168.16.4
- S03 - 192.168.16.5
- DB01 - 192.168.16.6
- WEB01 - 192.168.16.7

S01 is the main server: domain controller, file server, dns server and VPN server

When I connect from my home to the VPN (via the external IP address), and logon with my domain credentials, I get an IP (`192.168.16.44`), all correct.

However, when I try to ping (or RDP, or access a file share) the S01 server, I get a timeout.
When I look at a tracert to one of the other servers, I see something weird:

```
tracert 192.168.16.3

Tracing route to MS01 [192.168.16.3]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    32 ms    35 ms    33 ms  S01 [192.168.16.47]
  2    40 ms    34 ms    34 ms  MS01 [192.168.16.3]

Trace complete.
```

Hence the S01 IP, its `.47` instead of `.2`.
If I RDP to the server (via another server I **can** reach), I see the `.47` IP address is linked to a PPP adapter (I guess my VPN connection):

```
PPP adapter RAS (Dial In) Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.47
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I have no idea where I should look to solve this problem. Any tips? If you need more information, just ask.

As requested in the comments (new connection now, home ip is now `.42` instead of `.44`), netstat route dump from S01:

```
netstat -rn
===========================================================================
Interface List
 29...........................RAS (Dial In) Interface
 12...00 15 5d 0a 65 00 ......Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.16.254     192.168.16.2    261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.16.0    255.255.255.0         On-link      192.168.16.2    261
     192.168.16.2  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.16.2    261
    192.168.16.42  255.255.255.255    192.168.16.42    192.168.16.47     31
    192.168.16.47  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.16.47    286
   192.168.16.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.16.2    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.16.2    261
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.16.47    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      192.168.16.2    261
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.16.47    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.16.254  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    261 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    261 fe80::a873:ce0f:c053:a315/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    261 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

==edit
If I change the clent side, too set a fixed DNS server at `192.168.16.47`, it will fail also:

```
PPP adapter Office:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : Office.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Office
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.51(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.16.2
                                       192.168.16.47
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

However I set the DNS to the `.47`, it still sees the `.2` also (which still is the correct addrress in my opinion)

Comment: Look at your reverse DNS zones.  I am guessing you have some left over crap.

Comment: @Zoredache I also cant ping the IP, so I think its not an DNS issue

Comment: Could you dump a netstat -rn from the VPN system?

Comment: @ByronC. see my edit

Comment: Well it looks like the routing is correct. I am assuming there is some kind of NAT between your S01 server and your ISP. You might want to check your firewall on the S01 server. Ping, RDP, etc could be disabled.

Comment: Don't think its an firewall issue. From other servers in the network, or PCs directly connected to it, I can RDP to it.

Comment: Also with firewall disabled, it doesn't work. I can ping the S01 on its .47 address (which is made with the VPN connection)